# React Hooks - How to test a named function was called inside of componentDidMount in React with Enzyme/Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have a class based component and I'm converting it to Functional component,
and I'm having difficulty writing test for it with Enzyme.

I'm unable to replicate the `componentDidMount` behavior for Functional component.

Here is the test for Class based component, which works fine.

```
  it('componentDidMount() calls myCustomFunction()', () => {
> const instance = shallow(<MyComponent />).instance();
    instance.scoobyDoobyFunction = jest.fn();
    instance.componentDidMount();
    expect(instance.scoobyDoobyFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I'm not sure how to try that in Functional component.

I tried in the Functional component with the following:

```
const instance = mount(<MyComponent />);
    await runAllPromises();
    await instance.update();
    expect(instance.scoobyDoobyFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The following solution is the way that is suggested by `create-react-app`, the npm/yarn package responsible for most client-side react applications.

You can verify this solution by running the following commands:

```bash
yarn create react-app --template typescript
# or
npm create-react-app --template typescript
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Note that I replaced your `mount(...)` function with the `render(...)` function, which simulates a render of that component.

---

Obviously, the above code is in TypeScript (which is just a superset of JavaScript). In this case, the code should be mostly compatible to run in a pure JS environment (since no typings are used in this file).

---

Also note that ReactJS function constructors do not have the same lifecycle methods as class components like `componentDidMount`. Instead it uses the `useEffect` hook, which you can read more about [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect).